# How to return value from function to main thread?

Tags: javascript

I have get the following `switch`:

```
case "contacts":
    html = contacts(required_fields[h]);
    break;
```

Where `contacts` function is:

```
function contacts(data) {
    return getContacts(function (response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        var contacts = '';

        for (var c = 0; c < response.length; c++) {
            contacts += '<input id="id_' + data.id + '" name="feature_' + data.id + '" value="' + response[c].phone_number
                + '" class="form-control contacts required" placeholder="Телефон" type="text" required>';
        }

        return contacts;
    });
}
```

In result I get `undefined` returnedd value in line:

```
html = contacts(...)


function getContacts(callback) {
    $.get("/contacts/" + $('#account').val(), function (data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think in an js asynchron wait the value of the variable html is set later you need to use something like async/await or a promise.

```
function contacts(data) {
return getContacts(function (response) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    var contacts = '';

    for (var c = 0; c < response.length; c++) {
        contacts += '<input id="id_' + data.id + '" name="feature_' + data.id + '" value="' + response[c].phone_number
            + '" class="form-control contacts required" placeholder="Телефон" type="text" required>';
    }

    resolve(contacts);
    })
});
```

}

And in your switch

```
html = await contacts(required_fields[h]);
```

The function where the switch is needs to be async like

```
async function ....(){}
```

Comment: Lie callback function?

Comment: Yeah i would suggest you, to look promises in js up.

Comment: This isn't a great answer.It's a comment at best. Perhaps you could add some example code to explain what you mean.

Comment: Can you post your getContacts function?

Comment: Yes, I added this function in question